# time.time() library returns unexpected result when using joblib

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, timing

I have a program that creates several instances of a class, `Test` and then does some work on each instance of the class, keeping track of how much time the work took. I recently decided to parallelize this code using the `joblib` library, and am running into an error: the `total_time` variable at the end is now `0.0`.

The python environment on my machine is

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.0 (default, Sep 18 2018, 18:47:08) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.43.1)] on darwin
```

Below is an MCVE for this issue:

```
import time
import random
import multiprocessing
import joblib

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.duration = 0.0

def add_test(a):
    temp = Test()
    temp.name = str(a)
    return temp


def run_test(test):
    test_start = time.time()
    rand = random.randint(1,3)
    time.sleep(rand)
    test_end = time.time()
    test.duration = round(test_end - test_start, 3)
    print(f"Test {test.name} ran in {test.duration}")

def main():
    tests = []
    for a in range(1,10):
        tests.append(add_test(a))

    num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(joblib.delayed(run_test)(test) for test in tests)

    total_time = round(sum(test.duration for test in tests), 3)

    print(f"This run took {total_time} seconds.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I add a `print(list(test.duration for test in tests))` in `main()`, I see that `test.duration` is `0.0` after `run_test()` is called. can be seen from running the above input, `test.duration` is set to a non-zero value (where appropriate) inside `run_test()`.

I'm not too familiar with python classes or the `joblib` library, so I'm not sure if the issue I'm experiencing is related to a misuse of classes or some other issue that's beyond me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to [num8lock on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/9mkuh2/using_timetime_with_joblib_giving_an_unexpected/e7g83d9/) here is the correct way to solve this:

```
import time
import random
import multiprocessing
import joblib

class Test:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.duration = 0.0
        self.start = time.perf_counter()

    def run(self):
        rand = random.randint(1,3)
        time.sleep(rand)
        _end = time.perf_counter()
        self.duration = _end - self.start
        print(f"Test {self.name} ran in {self.duration}")
        return self.duration

def add(a):
    return Test(str(a))

def make_test(test):
    return test.run()

def main():
    num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    tests = []
    for a in range(1,10):
        tests.append(add(a))

    jobs = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(joblib.delayed(make_test)(t) for t in tests)
    total_time = sum(job for job in jobs)
    print(f"This run took {total_time} seconds.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```